# Why wouldn't they include the power of a working prototype?

Tags: patentability, us20140276685

In reference to the patent: [US 2014/0276685 A1](https://www.google.com/patents/US20140276685)

In the description of patent is not quantified the power required for hair cutting. The discussion about the required wavelengths is meaningless without the power indication. What was the power of a working prototype (if any)?

Comment: I redirected your question a bit to ask why this information might not be included in the patent (which is how it was answered). Unfortunately, questions about the underlying technology used to get these products to work is outside the scope of this site. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: To be clear, the linked document is not a patent, but a pre-grant publication of an **application** for a patent.

Answer (score 1):

A working prototype would be considered "reduction to practice", which is less important under the [AIA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leahy-Smith_America_Invents_Act) First to File rules. This particular application has a priority date of March 15, 2013, which is one day before those new rules went into affect (this is probably not a coincidence). Therefore, the application would be subject to reduction to practice implications under the pre-AIA rules (Section 2138). That section is lengthy, but the most relevant parts are copied below.

From [MPEP Chapter 2100, Section 2138: Pre-AIA 35 U.S.C. 102(g)](http://www.uspto.gov/web/offices/pac/mpep/s2138.html):

> *[Editor Note: This MPEP section **has limited applicability** to applications subject to examination under the first inventor to file
>   (FITF) provisions of the AIA as set forth in [35 U.S.C. 100 (note)](http://www.uspto.gov/web/offices/pac/mpep/mpep-9015-appx-l.html#al_d1d917_1bef1_2b). See
>   [MPEP § 2159](http://www.uspto.gov/web/offices/pac/mpep/s2159.html#ch2100_d20034_1dc34_1dd) et seq. to determine whether an application is subject to
>   examination under the FITF provisions, [MPEP § 2159.03](http://www.uspto.gov/web/offices/pac/mpep/s2159.html#ch2100_d222e3_13adb_2f9) for the
>   conditions under which this section applies to an AIA application, and
>   [MPEP § 2150](http://www.uspto.gov/web/offices/pac/mpep/s2150.html#ch2100_d2002f_22805_16e) et seq. for examination of applications subject to those
>   provisions.]*
>
> **Pre-AIA 35 U.S.C. 102 Conditions for patentability; novelty and loss of right to patent.**
>
> A person shall be entitled to a patent unless -
>
> ---
>
> (g)(1) during the course of an interference conducted under [section 135](http://www.uspto.gov/web/offices/pac/mpep/mpep-9015-appx-l.html#d0e303239) or [section 291](http://www.uspto.gov/web/offices/pac/mpep/mpep-9015-appx-l.html#d0e306203), another inventor involved therein
>   establishes, to the extent permitted in [section 104](http://www.uspto.gov/web/offices/pac/mpep/mpep-9015-appx-l.html#d0e302559), that before such
>   person’s invention thereof the invention was made by such other
>   inventor and not abandoned, suppressed, or concealed, or (2) before
>   such person’s invention thereof, the invention was made in this
>   country by another inventor who had not abandoned, suppressed, or
>   concealed it. In determining priority of invention under this
>   subsection, there shall be considered not only the respective dates of
>   conception and reduction to practice of the invention, but also the
>   reasonable diligence of one who was first to conceive and last to
>   reduce to practice, from a time prior to conception by the other.
>
> [Pre-AIA 35 U.S.C. 102(g)](http://www.uspto.gov/web/offices/pac/mpep/mpep-9015-appx-l.html#d0e302383) issues such as conception, reduction to
>   practice and diligence, while more commonly applied to interference
>   matters, also arise in other contexts.
>
> [Pre-AIA 35 U.S.C. 102(g)](http://www.uspto.gov/web/offices/pac/mpep/mpep-9015-appx-l.html#d0e302383) may form the basis for an *ex parte*
>   rejection if: (1) the subject matter at issue has been actually
>   reduced to practice by another before the applicant’s invention; and
>   (2) there has been no abandonment, suppression or concealment.
>
> To qualify as prior art under [pre-AIA 35 U.S.C. 102(g)](http://www.uspto.gov/web/offices/pac/mpep/mpep-9015-appx-l.html#d0e302383), however,
>   there must be evidence that the subject matter was actually reduced to
>   practice, in that conception alone is not sufficient. While the filing
>   of an application for patent is a constructive reduction to practice,
>   the filing of an application does not in itself provide the evidence
>   necessary to show an actual reduction to practice of any of the
>   subject matter disclosed in the application as is necessary to provide
>   the basis for an ex parte rejection under [pre-AIA 35 U.S.C.
>   102(g)](http://www.uspto.gov/web/offices/pac/mpep/mpep-9015-appx-l.html#d0e302383). Thus, absent evidence showing an actual reduction to
>   practice (which is generally not available during *ex parte*
>   examination), the disclosure of a United States patent application
>   publication or patent falls under [pre-AIA 35 U.S.C. 102(e)](http://www.uspto.gov/web/offices/pac/mpep/mpep-9015-appx-l.html#d0e302383) and
>   not under [pre-AIA 35 U.S.C. 102(g)](http://www.uspto.gov/web/offices/pac/mpep/mpep-9015-appx-l.html#d0e302383). The disclosure in a
>   reference United States patent does not fall under [pre-AIA 35 U.S.C.
>   102(g)](http://www.uspto.gov/web/offices/pac/mpep/mpep-9015-appx-l.html#d0e302383) but under [pre-AIA 35 U.S.C. 102(e)](http://www.uspto.gov/web/offices/pac/mpep/mpep-9015-appx-l.html#d0e302383).